# Does SpringWS implement WS-Trust / STS and SpringWS

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, spring-ws

I am developing a SOAP-WS Client to a WS-Trust using WebService.
As I want to use SpringBoot I usually use SpringWS.
But I can hardly find any information concerning how to request a token via SpringWS.
Using the WS-Security via wss4j works fine.
But wss4j is not implementing WS-Trust/STS. (?)

So do I have to use CXF as client ? Or another option ?

Comment: Looking for the same